# extension methods unintentionally copying argument

Tags: vector, reference, unity-game-engine, extension-methods

I can't get the extension method to work, It will run, but the Vector3 I put into it as an argument is not the same vector I manipulate inside the TurnClockWiseXZ method.

This is the class calling the method.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    void FixedUpdate () {

        Vector3 test = new Vector3(2,0,3);

        Debug.Log ("1: "+test); 
        test.TurnClockWiseXZ();
        Debug.Log ("2: "+test);
    }
}
```

This is where I add the Method:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public static class ExtendClass {

    public static void TurnClockWiseXZ( this Vector3 vector){
        float x = vector.z;
        float y = vector.y;
        float z = -vector.x;
        vector.Set(x,y,z);
    }
}
```

This is the debug messages I get:

1: (2.0, 0.0, 3.0)

2: (2.0, 0.0, 3.0)

This is what I want:

1: (2.0, 0.0, 3.0)

2: (3.0, 0.0, -2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, because Vector3 is a *struct* (and therefore a *value* type), it is always passed into a method by making a *copy* of itself (pass by value). For that reason, any modifications inside the extension method are only affecting the copy.

I see a few alternatives.

1) Make your extension method return the *new* copied vector and reset the outer variable. It would look like this when calling: `test = test.TurnClockwiseXZ();`

2) Use a static method instead (not an extension method) that returns void, but takes a vector as a `ref` parameter. So that would look like this: `ExtendClass.TurnClockwiseXZ(ref test);` And the definition would be `public void TurnClockwiseXZ(ref Vector3 vect)` This passes the vector by reference, so it modifies the outer variable inside the function.

3) If you are just modifying the position inside a transform most of the time (as I am), then you can have the extension method operate directly on the transform. Because the transform is a class (and not a struct), it is passed by reference by default and the extension method would work. That solution would look like this:

```
public void TurnClockwiseXZ(this Transform transform) {
     float x = transform.position.z;
     float y = transform.position.y;
     float z = -transform.position.x;
     transform.position = new Vector3(x,y,z);
}
```

And used as: `transform.TurnClockwiseXZ();`

I personally have extension methods for SetX, SetY, and SetZ on the transform to easily modify the position. Saves some hassle.